# How to Remove all Traces of a WordPress Plugin?

Tags: plugins

I've installed a couple of plugins like `ivory search` and some others, and now I want to remove them with all of their traces. I've tried the plugin section to deactivate and remove them, but it seems that some table/files/folder has been remained as junk.

How Can one do that? How do you handle this?

Comment: Unless the plugin implements a way to clean itself up, which is possible, then there’s no single answer that will cover all plugins. You would need to manually inspect all the files, tables and database entries to see where they came from and delete them by hand. If I were you I’d start by consulting the plugin’s documentation or asking it’s author. You’re not going to get much better than that unfortunately.

Comment: Oh☹, it will be overkill for me, is it worth to install from bare bone and add all the data from scratch and install only the plugins I've needed and have right now, and install a version on localhost to test plugins first at localhost then on production?

Comment: Having some left over data from a plugin is not a big deal. I wouldn’t worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Always deactivate and then delete the plugin from the WP plugin menu as opposed to in the file system.

You can google around, there is many plugins that remove orphan plugin tables and other data https://onlinemediamasters.com/clean-wordpress-database/

Just be careful and backup, I have done this numerous of times.

Comment: OP said they did deactivate the plugin from the plugin section.